# Benefit for jQuery("#item_id").val() over document.getElementById("item_id").value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any benefit to using jQuery over `getElementById()` to retrieve an input field's value?

```
jQuery("#item_id").val()

document.getElementById("item_id").value
```

In other words, is JQuery necessary to retrieve a value (i.e., does it cover special tricky cases)?

Comment: first of you can use $("#item_id").val() number one benefit for me is you have to type less

Comment: No, I can't, because I am using Drupal and it does not like $...

Comment: ohhh ok well it still less typing but if you are using drupal i would just use a regular js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only tricky cases that jQuery helps with are for select elements. The native way should be(is) faster.

**Edit to avoid confusion:**

native way is `document.getElementById("item_id").value`

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("item_id").value
```

is faster

http://jsperf.com/asdddddddddddddddddd

Answer (score 0):

If I am writing a script in jQuery, I will tend to just use the jQuery way of doing things, such as this example. It looks cleaner and follows the same syntax.

But I do believe `document.getElementById("item_id").value` is faster.

Answer (score 0):

the jQuery way, is cleaner but makes ppl not learn real and faster javascript.

Comment: This looks like flame bait. Using jQuery does not make people not learn anything. Not learning Javascript is the only way to not learn javascript.

Answer (score 0):

While `document.getElementById("item_id").value` is faster as others pointed out already, you should also consider the fact that `jQuery("#item_id").val()` is shorter, which means that your script will be downloaded faster.

You should always be optimizing **resources loading before DOM access**: it's like loading something from an HDD vs RAM.

Comment: of course, but I was assuming that you already have jQuery loaded in your page for something else

Answer (score 0):

If you are only retrieving the value, then the only benefit is syntax. However, if you are doing more work with the element, the jQuery method will return a jQuery object, which is much more useful than the DOM object.